# multiple (uneven row numbers) csv files into a matrix in R

Tags: r, csv, heatmap

Overall I want to make a heatmap in R using gplots. So I need to combine the csv files into a matrix. I have tried varoius attempts but I keep running into the problem of uneven row length.
Such as when I tried this approach from code I got

```
num.el <- sapply(a, length)
res <- cbind(unlist(a), rep(1:length(a), num.el))
```

I get error

```
  Error in structure(res, levels = lv, names = nm, class = "factor") : 
  'names' attribute [24] must be the same length as the vector [2]
```

I have 40+ csv files with uneven row numbers. I inclused two samples below

test1.csv

```
ark,
Actinocyclus actinochilus,7
Asterionella formosa,4
Aulacodiscus orientalis,1
Aulacoseira granulata,3
Chaetoceros radicans,1
Corethron hystrix,6
Coscinodiscaceae,1
Dactyliosolen fragilissimus,32
Diadesmis gallica,1
Diatoma hyemalis,1
Synedropsis hyperboreoides,4
Trigonium formosum,4
Urosolenia eriensis,2
```

test2.csv

```
ant,
Actinocyclus actinochilus,55
Asterionella formosa,3
Aulacoseira granulata,5
Chaetoceros radicans,7
Dactyliosolen fragilissimus,5
Diatoma hyemalis,5
Stephanopyxis turris,1
Striatella unipunctata,1
Synedropsis hyperboreoides,28
Trigonium formosum,3
Urosolenia eriensis,2
```

As you can see there is overlap in the name but the files are not exact matches. What would be the best way to over come the missing data for the heatmap to be built?

Comment: Do you need to keep the first line (ark, ant etc etc)?

Comment: I put them in for later for the heatmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you only have one "row" in the first column, so R doesn't know what to do with the names of your data.

Here we create a list of all the .csv files in the folder:

```
z <- list.files(pattern = ".*csv")
```

Then read in each file using `readLines`, then uses only the `2:end` of the data for the `read.table`, and take the first row as a name of the column:

```
data <- lapply(z, function(x) {temp <- readLines(x);
           read.table(text = temp[2:length(temp)], sep = ",", col.names = c("Species", temp[1]))})
```

Now your data should be a list of data frames.

I'm assuming you want to `merge` them:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), data)
```

Which gives me the following from your example data:

```
                       Species ark. ant.
1    Actinocyclus actinochilus    7   55
2         Asterionella formosa    4    3
3      Aulacodiscus orientalis    1   NA
4        Aulacoseira granulata    3    5
5         Chaetoceros radicans    1    7
6            Corethron hystrix    6   NA
7             Coscinodiscaceae    1   NA
8  Dactyliosolen fragilissimus   32    5
9            Diadesmis gallica    1   NA
10            Diatoma hyemalis    1    5
11  Synedropsis hyperboreoides    4   28
12          Trigonium formosum    4    3
13         Urosolenia eriensis    2    2
14        Stephanopyxis turris   NA    1
15      Striatella unipunctata   NA    1
```